# Angular Material FxLayout - align one button on the left and one on the right

Tags: flexbox, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

EDITED:

Does it exist a FxLayout directive to move the close button on the left and to leave others buttons on the right?
alternately how can i achieve the same result via css?

```
<div class="actions" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end center" fxLayoutGap="8px">
    <button mat-raised-button color="secondary" [mat-dialog-close]="true" >Close</button>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="previous()" >Previous</button>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="next()" >Next</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [angular-flex-layout](https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs)

```html
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
  <button> Other button</button>
  <div>
    <button mat-raised-button color="secondary" [mat-dialog-close]="true">
        Close</button>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="save()">
        Save</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using CSS

```css
.space-between-container {
  border: 1px solid #808080;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.flex-container {
  border: 1px solid #808080;
  display: flex;
}

.spacer {
  flex: 1 1 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="space-between-container">
  <button> Other button</button>
  <div>
    <button mat-raised-button color="secondary" [mat-dialog-close]="true">
        Close</button>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="save()">
        Save</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
  <button> Other button</button>
  <span class="spacer"></span>
  <button mat-raised-button color="secondary" [mat-dialog-close]="true">
        Close</button>
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="save()">
        Save</button>
</div>
```

Basically its using the CSS property [`justify-content: space-between`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)

Comment: your suggestion works but in my question  i forgot to mention that i've more than two buttons (my mistake,forgive me, i edited it!) the result i'd like to achieve is one button on the left and all the others on the right

Comment: @alex updated answer. you could just wrap the second *button group* in a div